# Small dataset not working well with prophet

Tags: python, forecasting, forecast, facebook-prophet

I am trying to use Prophet - the forecasting package by facebook, and it works great with say, 150 rows of data. But when I try to model with less than 100 rows, it gives me very weird predictions. When I do it in R, it gives me the same prediction for all dates and when I do it in python, it gives me very bad predictions.

My data is weekly from 2018 week 1 to 2019 week 40.

This is my code:
(python)

```
predictionSize=6
new_train_df = data[:-predictionSize]
new_test_df = data[len(data)-predictionSize:]

m_new = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=True,yearly_seasonality=True)
m_new.fit(new_train_df)

new_future = m_new.make_future_dataframe(periods=predictionSize,freq='W')
new_forecast = m_new.predict(new_future)

new_ypred = new_forecast[['ds', 'yhat', 'yhat_lower', 'yhat_upper']].tail(6)
```

Using this code gives me negative values for yhat.

My question is, are the predictions bad because the dataset is too less for prophet?

Do let me know if you need any other information. The data has weekly seasonality and yearly seasonality.

Comment: It would be useful to have the dataset, or a part of the data

Comment: Unfortunately the data is proprietary so I can't share it. The dataset I am having trouble with has 90 training points.